# Can we force all implementations to be singleton (objects)?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, singleton

Let's say we have an `abstract class` (same question for `traits` also):

```
abstract class TypeParser[C <: Changes : TypeTag] extends Serializable {

  val enrichmentType: EnrichmentType
  protected def parseChanges(row: Row): C

}
```

Where implementations look like the following:

```
object PlaceholderParser extends TypeParser[PlaceholderChanges] {

  val enrichmentType: EnrichmentType = PlaceholderType
  override protected def parseChanges(row: Row): PlaceholderChanges = ???

}
```

The above implementation is a singleton, however, it can't be forced to be a singleton for future implementations. So one can simply implement it as a `class`, for example:

```
class PlaceholderParser2() extends TypeParser[PlaceholderChanges2] {

  val enrichmentType: EnrichmentType = PlaceholderType2
  override protected def parseChanges(row: Row): PlaceholderChanges2 = ???

}
```

**Is there any way of forcing implementations to be a singleton?**

---

side question: is there any advantage of forcing it?

Comment: What's the goal of having only singletons?

Comment: Would you want a single possible instance of `TypeParser[T]` per type `T`?

Comment: You can make `TypeParser` a sealed abstract class and you would be able to extend it only in the same file. So you can create your objects or subclasses of  it only there.  In case you are making a library this is actually a good solution. Think about `List[T]` and `Nil`. `Nil` is an object of `List[Nothing]` but you can't extend `List[T]`.

Comment: @GaëlJ, I got it right. I want a single instance per type T. And they dont need state.

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip, that's an interesting solution, even though I normally like to break on class/object per file, except for enum-like objects created with sealed abstract class + case objects.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, that sounds interesting also. I've seen this kind of syntax around, but mainly on older projects like scala-test. Can you please point to a reading resource where I can delve deeper into it and learn it better?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you. Tested and it worked as expected. You should write this as the answer I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To our advantage all `objects` extend an interface called `Singleton`.
You can't extend it directly but we can use a **Scala** feature called [*self-types*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/self-types.html) to enforce that all subtypes of `TypeParser` to also be `Singletons` *(i.e. `objects`)*

```scala
abstract class TypeParser[C <: Changes : TypeTag] extends Serializable {
  self: Singleton =>
  ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent having 2 `objects` extending `TypeParser[T]` with the same `T` though. Unless I missed something?

Comment: @GaëlJ no it doesn't and AFAIK the only two ways to do that would be a `sealed trait` or dark magic in the form of very advanced macros. If that was part of the original requirement then I missed it and I apologize for that.

Comment: I think that's what OP really wanted so wanted to point it out. Your answer is still useful though ;)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez (side question) how would having a `sealed trait` prevent you from having multiple `objects` extending `TypeParser[T]` with the same `T`  ?  I'm just curious. I can't see how. You could still have `object obj1 extends TypeParser[Int]` and `object obj2 extends TypeParser[Int]` .

Comment: @AlinGabrielArhip sure, but since all would be in the same file and you would control all of them you can enforce that restriction.